# Extracting field value from Info table( .info ) in ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I am working on a Python snippet try to use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` to extract value of certain field from a Info Table which generated by executing `arcpy.Statistics_analysis()`.Here's my code:

```
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(fc,stats,[["Area","SUM"]],"")
Table = "D:/xxx/stats.info"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Table,["AREA_SUM"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        Number = row[0]
print Number
```

However I always got `RuntimeError: cannot open 'D:/xxx/stats.info'`. I think it's caused by improper file name extention, but I'm not sure what the correct one is.

Plus: is there any other possible way of extracting value from Info Table using arcpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isnt the dbase extension .dbf? Try placing the output from summary statistics in a file geodatabase, `stats = r'C:\data.gdb\sumstat'` then read this using the cursor.

But from what i can see there is no need for sumstat, you can do `print sum([i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'Area')])` (see [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))

Summary statistics is perhaps faster if your table is very big.